# Does NetSuite maintain different database for every user?

Tags: netsuite, erp

According to my understanding the central feature of all ERP systems is a shared database used by different business units.
So when any suite script is in 'Testing' mode  the changes made by the script are only visible to the user who has deployed it.The changes are visible to every user of the specified environment once the script in in 'Released' state. 
So does that mean Net Suite maintain different database for every logged in user?Or Does NetSuite use some different strategy? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer is No. Your understanding of the "Testing" Mode for the NetSuite Script Deployments is incorrect.

The script instance is only initiated only for the owner of the script when the script is in "Testing" Mode. However, any other user accessing the record will also see changes made to the record by the script.